# Lagrangian for the utility-mazimization of a household in a Menu Cost model, first order condition to Ci?

Tags: macroeconomics, utility, economic-growth, consumption, model

I need to solve the partial derivative to C_i of the integral provided below. I'd be more than happy for some help.

[image]

Based on the book's answer, we get:

[image]

Can someone explain how do we get there? And why does the subscript change from i to j?

Comment: You should use the chain rule: $[f(g(x))]' = f'(g(x))*g'(x)$. In your case, $g(x) = \int_{i=0}^{1} C_i^{\frac{\eta - 1}{\eta}} di$ and $f(g(x)) = g(x)^{\frac{\eta}{\eta - 1}}$.

Comment: Didn’t you miss another integral sign when typing the books answer?

Comment: You meant $C_i$ and $i$ to be different things, right? I interpret it as $i$ being the integration variable and $C_i$ being some function of $i$.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for providing with an answer :)
But I didn't type the solution myself, it is a screenshot from Romer's book on Advanced Macroeconomics and this is the solution the author provides when solving the maximization of the Lagrangian under the Menu Cost model

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved using Feynman’s differentiation under the integral sign.

By the chain rule,

$\frac{d}{dC_i} [\int_{i=0}^{1} C_i^\frac{\eta -1}{\eta} di ]^\frac{\eta}{\eta-1}$

$ = \frac{\eta}{\eta -1} [\int_{i=0}^{1} C_i^\frac{\eta -1}{\eta} di]^\frac{1}{\eta -1} \cdot \frac{d}{dC_i} [\int_{i=0}^{1} C_i^\frac{\eta -1}{\eta} di] $

Here is where we use Feynman’s technique (move the differential operator inside the integral):

$ = \frac{\eta}{\eta -1} [\int_{i=0}^{1} C_i^\frac{\eta -1}{\eta} di]^\frac{1}{\eta - 1}  \cdot \int_{i=0}^{1} \frac{\partial}{\partial C_i} C_{i}^\frac{\eta - 1}{\eta} di$

After differentiating, we get the answer:

$ = \frac{\eta}{\eta - 1} [\int_{i=0}^{1} C_i^\frac{\eta -1}{\eta} di]^\frac{1}{\eta - 1} \cdot \int_{i=0}^{1} \frac{\eta - 1}{\eta} C_{i}^{-\frac{1}{\eta}} di $

Taking the constant multiple outside the integral, which is the inverse of the first constant,

$= [\int_{i=0}^{1} C_i^\frac{\eta -1}{\eta} di]^\frac{1}{\eta - 1} \cdot \int_{i=0}^{1} C_{i}^{-\frac{1}{\eta}} di $

Comment: I didn’t find changing one subscript from $i$ to $j$ necessary. In my solution it doesn’t matter as it’s just a dummy variable (a variable only used to integrate).